# Why does my computer take so long to install?

Tags: system-installation

I've been installing Ubuntu overnight and it is still stuck at "Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda)...". The version I'm trying to install is 14.10. What's wrong? How should I install it?